# How do I create a Subclass of the "list" class, that sorts itself upon instantiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, super

I want to create `SortedList`, a subclass of the `list` class.
I want `SortedList` to **sort itself upon instantiation**.

For example, with this input:

```
x = SortedList([1, 9, 7])
print(x)
```

I would want this output:

```
[1, 7, 9]
```

I'm a begginer. I know there might some function or data type that's better for this, but I want to practice my dunder methods and OOP skills.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
class SortedList(list):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super().__init__()
        self.values = values
        self.sort(self.values)
```

I'm a bit confused.

I've used `super()` before, but I used it with superclasses that I made, where I knew the attributes.
This time, I have to use `super()` with a built-in class, so I'm not sure what attributes to write.

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
class SortedList(list):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super().__init__(sorted(values))

x = SortedList([1, 9, 7])
print(x)
```

A `list` can be built from an iterable, from an array for instance. We can thus pass a sorted copy of the values to the super constructor and let it initialize its attributes (we don't have to know the internals of `list`).

Note that if you really want to implement a SortedList, you'll have to keep on overriding the other methods!

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why the asker's solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will have error: `TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments`.

`self.sort` has issue, sort belongs to `list`, not instance of `list` or `SortedList`, `self` here is instance of `SortedList`. So, using `list.sort(self.values)` or `self.values.sort()` instead of `self.sort(self.values)` will work.

update: for more clear, with `a = [1, 2, 3]`, `a.sort() equals to list.sort(a)`. `sort` does not belong to instance of list in fact.

Sorry for my poor English. I feel I have not expressed it very well...

update again: yeah, I can show information with code:

```
In [18]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [19]: a.sort
Out[19]: <function list.sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)>
# but 
In [20]: a.sort is list.sort
Out[20]: False
# I think python makes some trick here...
# so...
In [21]: list.sort
Out[21]: <method 'sort' of 'list' objects>
```

Anyway, I hope you can understand why `self.sort(self.values)` can not work, with my not very expressive explanation.

It seems I forgot to show code which can work...

Based on my explanation:

```
class SortedList(list):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super().__init__(values)
        super().sort()
x = SortedList([1, 3, 2])
print(x)
```